# Form Sending To The Wrong PUT Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models for users ; the Plans model has_many users. Now, what I would like to do is to allow users to upgrade/downgrade their plans, by changing the plan_id. I've set up a form, as well as the appropriate action, but when I hit submit, it doesn't seem to do what the PUT action says. It seems to use the update action.

Here's my form :

```
                       <%= form_tag("/users/update_plan", :method => "put" ) do %>

                        <%= hidden_field_tag :plan_id, plan.id %>

                        <%= submit_tag("Change To Plan", :class => "signup") %>


                      <% end %>
```

Here's my update action

```
  def update_plan
   @user = current_user
   @user.plan_id = params[:plan_id]
   @user.save
   sign_in @user
   redirect_to change_plan
  end
```

When I submit the form above though, it not only doesn't register the change, but I think it uses the update action, and not the update_plan action. The reason I think this is because it redirects to the what's in the update action, and it flashes the same thing as the update action.

```
  def update
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Here's my routes.rb file

```
Dentist::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :phones, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :find_numbers, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]  

  put 'users/update_plan'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/login',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  match '/change_plan',  to: 'users#change_plan'

  root  to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/product_demo', to: 'static_pages#product_demo'

  match '/pricing', to: 'plans#index'

  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

And here's a console screenshot of what's happening:

http://stepanp.com/debug3.jpg

It seems to say it's using the update_plan action, but... :S

Any help on trying to get Update_plan action to function would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is going to the right place (/users/update_plan), but that is being routed to:

```
UsersController#update
```

as it says on the second line of your console log. So not the action you expect, and the problem is in your routes. Try this to list all your routes:

```
rake routes
```

Probably the users update route (created by resources :users) is catching this first:

```
PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                   users#update
```

There are no restrictions on the content of id, and format is optional, so users/update_plan would call users/update with an id of update_plan (in fact you can see that is happening at the edge of your console log screenshot, look for the :id => parameter).

So I would move your custom route to the top of the routes file first above resources :users, and also try change it to direct to the action you want, not sure what a route with no action specified does...

```
 put '/users/update_plan',  to: 'users#update_plan'
```